# Spring Controller не работает

Tags: spring-mvc

помогите пожалуйста. Это первое, что я делаю на Spring, по- этому никаких идей у меня нет.
Проблема в том, что при запуске должно выдавать страницу с текстом из файла first.jsp, но оно выводит страницу из файла index.jsp. В начале, следуя уроку, я вообще удалила index.jsp, но в таком случае выходила ошибка 404. Т.е. мой контроллер вообще не виден и не задействован.

Структура файлов:

[image]

Файл applicationContext.xml:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Controller:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFTvU.png)

pom.xml:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

web.xml:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пока проблему не видно, покажите ваш pom.xml и web.xml файлы. Какую URL вы открываете в браузере?

Comment: Я добавила pom и web

Comment: В браузере открывается http://localhost:8080/

Answer (score 0):

2 наиболее вероятных проблемы:

1. Проверьте настройки вашего томкат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В браузере вам необходимо открывать именно ту URL, которая указана в вашем томкат сервере. Соблюдая все слешы и т.д. Не факт что у вас там просто указан локалхост. Проверьте.

2)Вы используете зависимость JSTL от Jun 23, 2011 вместе с зависимостями Spring от Apr 13, 2023. Разница 12 лет! Вполне возможна несовместимость версий. Попробуйте более старые версии для всех Spring dependency. Я нашел старый проект, в котором Spring зависимоти "5.2.9.RELEASE" и все отлично работает с вашей версией JSTL. Попробуйте эти версии.

Если оба варианта не помогли - то забросьте ваш проект на гитхаб - так будет легче разобраться в чем действительно дело. Тем более вы скинули скриншоты, а не копипаст фаших файлов, так что воспроизвести у себя ваш проект проблематично

Comment: Да, думаю причина именно в том, что имеется несовместимость версий, и мне предстоит разобраться именно с этим.

Comment: Замените все ваши "6.0.8" в pom.xml на "5.2.9.RELEASE" и попробуйте запустить

Comment: При замене на 5.2.9.RELEASE , они все выделяются красным и  не запускается.

Comment: а вы подгрузили новые зависимости? ctrl+shift+O кажется. Если красным подсвечивает, то какую ошибку выдает?